# Why are the acceptedTypes not set in Richfaces Drag and Drop?

Tags: jsf, drag-and-drop, richfaces, liferay-6, jsf-1.2

I've tested the Example from [Richfaces DragandDrop](http://showcase.richfaces.org:8000/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=dragDrop&skin=blueSky) draging is working correctly, but every time i try to drop an element at the dropzone, it's being rejected.

```html
  <rich:dragIndicator id="indicator" />
            <h:panelGrid columnClasses="panelc" columns="2" width="100%">

                <rich:panel>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Verfügbare Spalten" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:dataTable id="src" columns="1"
                        value="#{columnBean.possibleColumns}" var="col">

                        <h:column>

                            <a4j:outputPanel
                                style="width:100px;border:1px solid gray;padding:2px"
                                onmouseover="this.style.cursor='move'" layout="block">
                                <rich:dragSupport dragIndicator=":indicator" dragType="#{columnBean.test}"
                                    dragValue="#{col}">
                                    <rich:dndParam name="label" value="#{col.label}" />
                                </rich:dragSupport>
                                <h:outputText value="#{col.label}" />
                                <!--        <br />
                            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="#{col.id}Possible"
                                    value="#{col.rendered}"
                                    style="width:100%;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto" />-->
                            </a4j:outputPanel>
                        </h:column>
                        <f:facet name="footer">
                            <a4j:commandButton value="Reset" action="#{columnBean.reset}"
                                reRender="src,activeColumns" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </h:dataTable>
                </rich:panel>


                <h:panelGrid columns="3" width="100%">

                    <rich:panel style="width:90%">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Aktive Spalten" />
                        </f:facet>

                        <rich:dropSupport acceptedTypes="#{columnBean.test}"
                            dropListener="#{columnBean.processDrop}"  
                            reRender="activeColumn,src">
                        </rich:dropSupport>

                        <h:dataTable id="activeColumns" columns="1"
                            value="#{columnBean.columns}" var="column">
                            <h:column>
                                <h:outputText value="#{column.label}"
                                    style="border:1px solid gray" />
                            </h:column>
                        </h:dataTable>

                    </rich:panel>

                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:panelGrid>
```

When I look in my browsers-developertools i can see that acceptedType is empty.
Even if I set the dragType and the acceptedType as a String.

I speculate that this error has something to do with lifreay 6.2.3 interfering the setting. Am I right?

Comment: You are using RichFaces 3 and using a demo for RichFaces 4.5, the attributes are not the same.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but the attributes are the same in Richfaces 3.3.3-Final. I posted the wrong link. this is the right one: http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dragSupport.jsf